# Unable to unzip files in PHP

Tags: php, zip

For the past hour I have been searching, adding, and failing on how to unzip a file.
I am downloading zips regularly using php. I need to extract the contents of the zip to a folder called zips, doesn't really matter (just not same directory). I'm using shared hosting with unlimited space and bandwidth if that makes any difference.

The zip I download is 1 zip with 5 zips inside, and 1 csv within each of those 5 zips. I need to read each csv and store the info into a database, which I already have the code for but I can't open any of the zip files.

I have tried the following code, and I have had no luck on either of them.
I also tried the unzip functions on php.net with no luck either.

Any Suggestions?

```
$local_file = '_08222012_213000.zip';
$zip = zip_open($local_file);
if (is_resource($zip)) {
  while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
    $fp = fopen(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), "w");
    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
      $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
      fwrite($fp,"$buf");
      zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
      fclose($fp);
    }
  }
  zip_close($zip);
}
```

This one didn't work either:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($local_file);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('zips/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
}
```

Edit: I got this code to work if anyone else has the problem in the future.

```
//Change directory
chdir("zips/");
exec("unzip ./$local_file");
```

Comment: The strings "had no luck" and "didn't work" are not built-in error messages in PHP. Exactly **how** did your code not work? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: What happens? Do you get any error message? Have you enabled error messages in PHP?

Comment: The only error messages I got was below but that was pointed out on php.net: Warning: zip_read() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home/cindyhod/public_html/test/ftp/ftp2.php on line 72

Comment: I echo "Starting unzip" and then nothing, or "failed" using the bottom example. And yes, errors are enabled.

Comment: Opening the zip file is failing; my guess would be that your file path is incorrect.

Comment: How would I correct this? realpath($local_file) ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that you do not have zip support installed on your PHP installation. If you're using windows, PHP should come with the DLL (from what I recall) and you should enable it in your PHP.ini file by finding the extensions= line that corresponds to it.

If you're using Linux, depending on your distribution you can install that extension through your package manager. Or by doing:

```
sudo pecl install zip
```

For more info on how to install it please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php .

The other suggestion I have is to make sure that the permissions on the file are such that the PHP process (which generally runs as the webserver process) can access the file. Also make sure that the path is accessible to the webserver, I.E. in a public_html directory (it's considered a best practice on shared hosting to chroot PHP to the webroot directory).

Comment: @Ilikephp Ask your host to enable/install the zip extension. You can verify that I'm correct about this by checking out the results of echo phpinfo(); Without the zip extension you're not going to be able to do this (unless you want to write a pure PHP implementation of zip... Which would be pointless).

Comment: Where would I be looking for to see if zips are enabled? At the bottom "Registered PHP Streams   |   https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip" zip is the last one.

Comment: Oh duh, at the bottom it says zip | enabled. so that's not the problem. :/

Comment: @Ilikephp That leaves permissions or path. Make sure the zip files are readable by the apache process, make sure they're in a path accessible under the webroot.

Comment: I currently have it in a sub domain on the pubic_html directory, what about permissions? I don't really understand those so that could be the problem. What permissions should I change, the file or the folder, or the zip I download? and to what? 777?